What is meaning of "BHCK" in report FR Y-9C
FR Y-9C report: FRY9C
There is some code like BHCK/BHCY etc for example in the page of No.46 in report link.
I guess BHC mean bank holding company, then what is the meaning of "K" or "A" etc.

Thanks in advanced.

Why downvote? Any guide?

Partly because you are new to this stack, and it looked like a setup for a spam answer (now deleted). If it is a genuine question (I now see you've been active for a while on other stacks), then, to me at least, it seems to lack clarity/context. Can you [edit] in where you have seen those codes? Perhaps quote part of the source?

More context would help, for those of us who don't recognize that form number.

@TripeHound  I updated the context, thanks.

@keshlam updated, thanks

Instead of linking to some unknown destination, why don't you just provide context in the question? What's "FR Y-9C" and how is it relevant to personal finance?

Those are the first four characters of the MDRM identifier(called the  mnemonic in documentation, map to reporting form/data collection name) and then on the rows beneath are the item codes (last 4 characters of the MDRM identifier).
You can download the csv lookup here, it contains the decodes for many reporting forms:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/mdrm/download_mdrm.htm
You'll sometimes see them as all 8 characters, for example:
BHCYJA36 = Available-for-sale debt securities and equity securities with readily determinable fair values not held for trading purposes. Reported on the FR Y-9C.
It's thoroughly documented but not terribly intuitive/easy to use.
